# Подскажите как можно реализовать данную задачу

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как можно реализовать подобный интерфейс:

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206132423/https://laragon.org/)

Или может есть где-то пример. При движении мышки, на заднем фоне рандомно рисуются объекты по точкам и совсем непонятно как это реализовано. Не уверен, но возможно это js.

Comment: Открой инспектор и посмотри подключаемые скрипты. Там даже комментарии есть - для чего какой используется

Answer (score -5, accepted):

https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#default

Возможно, поможет. поиграть с настройками надо.

Comment: День добрый. Старайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, а не просто ссылки.

Comment: Человек спросил чем можно это реализовать, я закинул ссылку на библиотеку, прямо с визуальным редактором где можно под себя настроить до тонкостей. ) Что подробнее то ?)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Только я так понял это лицензированное решение?

Comment: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md --- MIT лицензия, можно использовать и для личных, и для коммерческих проектов. Такое ощущение что минусы ставят, даже не открыв линк..

Comment: видимо так и это печально (

Comment: @АлександрЮзвяк, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как «принятый», нажав галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: Просто не любят ответы-ссылки. Вы бы могли какой-нибудь пример с этой либой добавить в ответ)

Comment: @АлександрЮзвяк минусы ставят, потому что ответ обязан быть полноценным и по возможности самодостаточным даже без открытий линков. В противном случае он рано или поздно будет удалён модераторами (но конкретно Suvitruf видимо ещё слишком добрый)

Comment: @andreymal модераторы удаляют обычно спам и т.п, подобные ответы может и само сообщество удалить (проголосовав за удаление).